# Speeding up time-consuming list operations using cython

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, cython, processing-efficiency

I have a function that takes an image represented in a numpy ndarray as a parameter.
This ndarray consists of a *list* x *list* x *list* item (line x pixels x pixel) and needs to be transformed to a *list* x *list* x *tuple* in regular list format (thus no longer as an ndarray).

thus for instance the contents of this variable may look like

```
[[[0,0,0],[1,0,1],[2,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[1,7,4],[1,3,5]],[[2,4,2],[1,6,7],[1,9,0]]]
```

and should be turned into:

```
[[(0,0,0),(1,0,1),(2,4,5)],[(3,4,5),(1,7,4),(1,3,5)],[(2,4,2),(1,6,7),(1,9,0)]]
```

The (cython) code segment below does exactly this, but takes around 800ms for an image of 1024x768 to complete.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def convertToBackdrop(np.ndarray arr3d):    
    agc = arr3d.swapaxes(0,1).tolist()
    agc = [map(tuple,line) for line in agc]
    return agc
```

My quesion is: in what ways could I make this code more (time-)efficient? I have searched if there is cdef for list, but have not found any leads. I hope I'm not asking for the impossible if I'd like to get it under 100 ms completion time. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to convert a list to a tuple? Anything a tuple can do, a list can do.

Comment: I supply this list to a different function of an external module that interfaces with a so-called EyeLink, which is a device we use in psychology to track eyemovements. If the variable is in the correct list x list x tuple format, that function takes around 14 ms to return. If I supply it with a list x list x list formatted variable, it somehow takes over 1000 ms to return! I was amazed by this as well at first, but in the end I decided it's probably best if I take care of the conversion to the right format myself...

Comment: That's odd. There are performance differences between tuples and lists, but I wouldn't expect it to be so dramatic. It's a shame numpy doesn't offer a `totuple()` method. Out of interest, what is the costly part of the method, the `tolist()` or the list comp?

Comment: the tolist() function of ndarray takes on average 451ms to complete.
the segment that converts the necessary list items to tuples takes on average 279ms. The other peculiar thing is that I obtain the ndarray by converting it from a Pygame surface (pygame.surfarray.array3d). Though I'd expect this operation to be far more time intensive, it only takes around 46ms on average to complete...

Comment: Is it necessary to do the conversion to a list first, can you not do the list comprehension directly over the numpy array? (This may be a stupid question, I'm not that familiar with numpy).

Comment: Yes, that what I've been trying, but have succeeded.
If you apply the [map(tuple,line) for line in agc] directly to the ndarray, it takes a lot longer than for a normal list. There are some interesting functions offered by numpy that let you iterate through the array, but they all return a flattened array, and I need it to retain its dimensions.

Comment: How odd. Maybe it would actually be faster to flatten it and then rebuild it into tuples - it's counter-intuitive, but possible. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas after that. The `grouper()` recipe from [the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) might be helpful with that.

Comment: Hmmm that might be a good idea. I'll try that and keep you posted

Comment: @Lattyware, unless you want to pass the three values into a set while keeping them together. `s = set(), xs = [1,2,3], s.update(xs), print(s), {1,2,3}, s.add(tuple(xs)), print(s), { 1, 2, 3, (1,2,3) }`

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus If that's a `why to use a tuple over a list`, yes, tuples not being mutable is one of the cases where a tuple could be needed (the description of the problem lead me to believe this was not the case).

Comment: I very much doubt that doing this in Cython will yield any benefit over ordinary Python. `map` and list comprehensions are already quite well optimized. Also, knowing the data type won't improve `tolist` performance since the expensive part is allocating all the lists and converting the Numpy data to Python objects.